# Does a class implementing service operations need to be wired up for every action?

Tags: topshelf

If a class implements `ServiceControl`, `ServiceSuspend`, `ServiceShutdown`, `ServiceCustomCommand`, `ServicePowerEvent` and/or `ServiceSessionChange`, do those actions still have to be wired up through `HostConfigurator`s `WhenXXX` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the service class implements the interfaces, such as ServiceControl, then there is no need to configure the `WhenStarted` and other methods since Topshelf will use the interface methods.

From the docs: http://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/config_api.html#simple-service

Comment: What happens if I call them anyway?

Comment: I don't know, I never thought to even try.